# How do I cache all the members in the server when starting the bot using discordjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I currently need to **ping** the person first then it will **cache** into the bot. After that, I would then be able to use their **ID**.

How do I make it so I can use their **ID** straight away?

This is my avatar command. How would I go to improve and add that command?

```
module.exports = {
    config,
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        let mention = message.mentions.members.first()
        if(!mention && !isNaN(args[0]) && args[0]) try {mention = await client.users.fetch(args[0])} catch (err) {}
        if(!mention && args[0] && isNaN(args[0])) try {mention = await message.guild.members.fetch({query: args[0], limit: 1})} catch (err) {}
        if(!mention) mention = message.author
        if(mention.roles) mention = mention.user
        let user = message.mentions.users.first()
          || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])?.user
          || message.author;
            embed.setTitle('Avatar!');
            embed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL());
            embed.setColor(client.config.colors.info);
            embed.setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}));
            return message.reply({embeds: [embed] });
        }
}
```

Comment: No pinging required at all for getting member's ID; when you sign the bot in it creates a cached listing of users in maps and will update on its own as users come available. You may reference this list by guild.

Answer (score 1):

*You don't have to.*

All members will be cached when your bot starts up (remember to put `const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });` in your file!)

See the first code block [here](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#implementation) (under implementation).

Comment: @novonimo, I have updated my question. Could you further help me? Thanks.

Comment: ahem the author of the question is me

Comment: @Capt171 This is an answer, not a question

Comment: oops sry my bad *answer